# CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD is being updated to gnu++14

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native

Just upgraded:

- react-native to 0.71.4
- react to 18.2.0

From that point whenever I run `pod install` I get the following warnings.
It takes something like 5-6 minutes to complete this update...
Tried in Xcode to `cmd + Delete` "C++ Language Dialect" but it keeps getting back to "gnu++14"

How to stop those warnings?

```
Pod install took 16 [s] to run
Setting REACT_NATIVE build settings
Setting CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD to gnu++14 on [path_to_my_project].xcodeproj
Pod install took 19 [s] to run
Setting REACT_NATIVE build settings
Setting CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD to gnu++14 on [path_to_my_project].xcodeproj
Pod install took 21 [s] to run
Setting REACT_NATIVE build settings
Setting CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD to gnu++14 on [path_to_my_project].xcodeproj
Pod install took 24 [s] to run
Setting REACT_NATIVE build settings
Setting CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD to gnu++14 on [path_to_my_project].xcodeproj
Pod install took 26 [s] to run
Setting REACT_NATIVE build settings
Setting CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD to gnu++14 on [path_to_my_project].xcodeproj
Pod install took 29 [s] to run
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got hit by https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia/issues/405 or similar. The solution could be to manually specify the standard in your **.podspec** files, e.g.

```
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    …
    "CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" => "c++17",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by commenting out the following section in my Podfile - not sure but I think its related to "react_native_post_install":

```
# Delete the following...

post_install do |installer|
  # Flipper Support for IOS 12/2020 - Start
  # flipper_post_install(installer)
  # Flipper Support for IOS 12/2020 - End
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE'] = 'bitcode'
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  react_native_post_install(installer)
        __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end

  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["DEVELOPMENT_TEAM"] = "***********"
     end
    end
  end
end
```